# Ramda Negation In Both

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

Why does the following fail to return a function?

```
const isValid = both(not(isEmpty), is(Object));
```

The item is valid if it:

1. Exists
2. Is an Array
3. Is not empty

Comment: Docs for `not`: "A function that returns the ! of its argument. It will return true when passed false-y value, and false when passed a truth-y one". `isEmpty` is truthy, as it is a reference to an existing function. Beware it is a *reference to the function*, not the result of calling that function.

Comment: What does it return for you ? How do you import Ramda ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, `not` is, ahem, *not* what you want. 
Instead, try `complement`:

```js
const isValid = R.both(R.complement(R.isEmpty), R.is(Array));
console.log(isValid);
console.log(isValid([1,2,3]));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ramda@latest/dist/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: My complements. Not a bad answer. I'll get my coat.

Comment: `not` inverts values, `complement` inverts functions (or the result of functions)